# Getting chat messages in rails API only application

Tags: many-to-many, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I have a two models one is `User` and another is `Message`. `User` model has one attribute name and `Message`model has one attribute called text. There is a many-to -many relationship between User and Message. Now think of two users John And Jane I want to retrieve all messages that simultaneously belong to John and Jane. How do I do it .

User Model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :messages
```

Message Model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Comment: please free feel to change anything

Comment: Why should one message belong to many users?

Comment: one is who is sending the message and the other is receiving message , because I need to have different chat rooms where I have to differentiate it

Comment: I dont know if you have better structure feel free to suggest it

Answer (score 1):

I would do it something like this:

```
Message.includes(:users).where(users: { name: %w(John Jane) })
```

Breaking this down:

```
# Enable user conditions in the messages query
Message.includes(:users)

# Then take messages belonging to Jane and John
.where(users: { name: %w(John Jane) })
```

Comment: can you explain whats going on here im new to rails